# Can you scale small icons (and only small icons) in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, icons

I know you can scale icons, text, and apps via the Display menu. I know that you can change views to 'medium', 'large', etc. However, is it possible to scale up *only* small icons? The reason for this ask is the universal scale via Display scales everything up, and that's unnecessary especially on a small laptop screen. Changing the icon view helps, but sadly 'details' view is the most utilitarian but only uses small icons.

Edit: Here is a screenshot of the icon size I'm referencing.

[image: screenshot of the icon size I'm referencing]

You can make the icons bigger by choosing 'Medium Icons' etc, but you lose the utility of the 'Details' view. 'List', 'Small Icons', and 'Details' all have the same size icons. Is there any way to make the icons in that view bigger?

Comment: Do you mean desktop icons?

Comment: Some screen shots would help us understand your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: I edited my post for added clarification, sorry for not including that before.

Comment: I guess you’re talking about File Explorer (previously known as Windows Explorer).  What ‘‘Display menu’’ are you talking about?  Please don’t make us guess.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question again to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: The only way I know how to do this would be use a different shell other than file explorer.